# BingMaps v8 CORS issue with IE11 edge

Tags: bing-maps

I have been searching for a workaround all day and I could not find the same exact problem that I find with the new bingmaps v8 library.

So I have bingmaps v8 and a tile service all set up on my system and it works well for all browsers, except on IE 11 Edge. (I know, what a surprise huh..) It actually even works with IE 10 and older..

Also the strange thing is that when scrolling in and out the map control it loads my tilelayer images fine. It only fails after I use setVisibility on my tilelayer, false and true again and then it fails downloading some of the tiles, giving me aborted calls to my service.

Also another question is - why is it reloading my TileSource image all together when all I am doing is toggling the visibility of my tilelayer ? It was not the case with bingmaps v7, I used to be able to just hide and show my tilelayer and I never seen calls  reappearing in the network section.. this must be a new "feature" of the v8 maps..
[image]
Please advise this specific scenario, I am running out of clues and forums..

```
function showHideLayer(layerId, boolStatus) {
    var layer = FindMyLayer(map.layers, layerId);

    if (layer) {
        layer.setVisible(boolStatus);
    }

}
```

Comment: Question in MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bea3b5ae-3ba2-4b14-b347-e9bd27a739c6/bingmaps-v8-cors-issue-with-ie11-edge?forum=bingmapsajax

Answer (score 0):

This should be resolved. Bing Maps V8 used to enable COR's on tile layers by default as this provides the ability to do some additional things with the data, however, it requires your tile server to have COR's enabled. V8 has now reverted this and has added an optional map option to enable CORs (map option currently in experimental branch and will be in main release branch in a couple of weeks).